# Send data to php file using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a trouble receiving data sent using ajax in a php file. It seems that ajax sends data, cause I get a success message, but php page shows me an error "Notice: Undefined index: ab".

Here is my jquery code for sending data using AJAX:

```
$('#download-btn').click(function(){
    var ab="abc";
    $.ajax({
        url:'generate_url.php',
        data:{'ab':ab},
        type:'post',
        success:function(data) {alert("sent");},
        error: function(request, status, error) {alert(request,status);}
    }); 
}
```

And that's how I extract data in a generate_url.php:

```
<?php
    $a = $_POST['ab'];
    echo $a;
?>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: It looks like it should work. What does `var_dump($_POST);` show?

Comment: How are you seeing what's in the PHP page? The success function doesn't display `data`.

Comment: You're missing the `)` at the end of the function.

Comment: `success:function(data) { alert("sent...next see the data..."); alert(data); },` is one way, but you need to find your javascript console.  what browser are you using?

Comment: @WEBjuju I know that's how he could see it, but I wonder what he's actually doing. My suspicion is that he's looking at a different page, and expecting the variable to stick around.

Comment: I'm not he, but she)) New to php and ajax but I try to do my best) The result of var_dump($_POST) is following: array (size=3)
  'cmd' => string '_s-xclick' (length=9)
  'hosted_button_id' => string '' (length=0)
  'submit' => string '' (length=0)

Comment: When I try to look what console tells me using `success:function(data) {console.log(data);}`, i get the code of the whole html page and not the data I'm sending. Is there something I don't understand or doing wrong?

Comment: @Bar close as Typo, yes?

Comment: @mickmackusa It must have been a copying error, since they were getting results from the AJAX request, not a JS syntax error.

Comment: @Bar so does the accepted answer resolve _that_ issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `);` from your code. For simple `POST` I'll advice you to use `$.post` (there's nothing special about `$.post`, it's a shorthand way of using `$.ajax` for `POST` requests.

```
$('#download-btn').on('click', function(){
    var ab="abc";
    $.post('generate_url.php', {'ab':ab}, function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `);` at the end of the ajax code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function($) {
            $('#download-btn').click(function(){
                var ab='abc';
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'generate_url.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {'ab':ab}
                })
                .done(function(respose) {
                    //todo
                })
            });
        })
    </script>
```

Comment: why `document` instead of button click?

Answer (score 0):

You were missing ')' in your javascript code

This will work:

```
$('#download-btn').click(function () {
    var ab = "abc";
    $.ajax({
        url: 'generate_url.php',
        data: {'ab': ab},
        type: 'post',
        success: function (data) {
            alert("sent");
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert(request, status);
        }
    });
});
```