# Change dropdown to dependent dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

As shown in the below code, **Semester** dropdown and **Programme** dropdown is current working separately where it isn't depend to each other.

How to change it to a dependent dropdown?

Eg: When user select the 31934 semester, only program(student_prg) that exists under that semester(semester) should display in the program dropdown.

**Code**

```
<div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="title">Select Current Semester:</label>
                  <select name="semester" class="form-control">
                      <option value="">--- Select Current Semester ---</option>

                      <?php
                        require('../setting/config.php');
                          $query = "SELECT DISTINCT semester FROM marketing_data ORDER BY semester DESC"; 
                          $do = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($do)){
                              echo '<option value="'.$row['student_matric'].'">'.$row['semester'].'</option>';
                          }
                      ?>
                  </select>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="title">Select Programme:</label>
                  <select id="prg" name="prg" class="form-control">
                    <option value="">--- Select Programme ---</option>

                    <?php
                        $query2 = "SELECT student_prg, COUNT(student_prg) as count FROM marketing_data GROUP BY student_prg ORDER BY student_prg DESC"; 
                          $do = mysqli_query($conn, $query2);
                          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($do)){
                              echo '<option value="'.$row['student_matric'].'" data-count="'.$row['count'].'">'.$row['student_prg'].'</option>';
                          }
                    ?>
                  </select>
```

**Screenshot**

[image: Screenshot]

**Database**

```
mysql> describe marketing_data;
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+--------------------+
| Field         | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+--------------------+
| student_matric| varchar(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| student_prg   | text unsigned        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| semester      | varchar(10)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| intake_year   | int(10)              | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| student_city  | text                 | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| city_lat      | varchar(20)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| city_long     | varchar(20)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| student_state | text                 | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| state_code    | varchar(100)         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+--------------------+
```

**Reply to the comment** @VPC

When I select the **Semester**, the **program** dropdown becomes empty.
[image]

After refresh the page, when I select **program** all the **semesters** able to view in the dropdown.
[image]

Comment: How large is the data set?  permutations?

Comment: You need some  ajax to update the second dropdown according to a selected value of the above dropdown

Comment: @SaydFuad , earlier I've tried ajax from https://phppot.com/demo/jquery-dependent-dropdown-list-countries-and-states/ and change the code according to my system. But then in my system, the two dropdowns is from the same MySQL table.

Comment: In the example that I've seen, the dependent dropdown are from different MySQL table. For instance, for state dropdown will be state table and for city dropdown will be city table.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Select Current Semester:</label>
        <select name="semester" class="form-control">
            <option value="" selected disabled>--- Select Current Semester ---</option> // Don't allow them to re-select this value 

            <?php
            require('../setting/config.php');
            $query = "SELECT DISTINCT semester FROM marketing_data ORDER BY semester DESC";
            $do = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($do)) {
                echo '<option value="' . $row['student_matric'] . '">' . $row['semester'] . '</option>';
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Select Programme:</label>
        <select id="prg" name="prg" class="form-control">
            <option value="" selected disabled>--- Select Programme ---</option> // Don't allow them to re-select this value

            <?php
            //get semester field also the result
            $query2 = "SELECT student_prg , semester, COUNT(student_prg) as count FROM marketing_data GROUP BY student_prg ORDER BY student_prg DESC";
            $do = mysqli_query($conn, $query2);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($do)) {
                //we are trying to add a common class to all the options 
                //then another class with semester id appended into it so it will be relevent to the specific semester expecting that semester field contains the semester code of other dropdown
                echo '<option class="hidden_options semester_' . $row['semester'] . '" value="' . $row['student_matric'] . '" data-count="' . $row['count'] . '">' . $row['student_prg'] . '</option>';
            }
            ?>
        </select>

        <script>
            //what we are trying to achieve here is when the user selects a semester, first it will hide all the option from programme dropdown then it will only show option which have the class sememter_$semeter_code
            $("select[name='semester']").change(function() {
                var selectValue = $(this).text(); //current semester text i.e semester code
                $('.hidden_options').hide(); //hide all the options
                $('.semester_' + selectValue).show(); //show only options with semester value prefixed into it
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply @VPC ... The dependent dropdown seems alike not working as expected. I've attached the explaination with the screen capture at the above. Please assist to check.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: @DollySha do the steps to check what's going wrong 
   check if option have classes applied
 check if jquery have fetched the semester select option text
 check if jqeury code doesn't have any error

Comment: The more efficient way is of course with ajax if you have lots of data to show. This is just a trick to achieve the goal.

Comment: @Dharman yes sir. I always try to write re-usable codes. In the future, I'll definitely keep your suggestion in mind before writing an answer to someone. Thanks.

Comment: @VPC so can I use ajax for the dropdowns which is from the same MySQL table? Could you give me any source link maybe to refer? Because I mostly seen an ajax dependent dropdown using more than one table.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41048272/send-data-to-php-file-using-ajax